# What is the advantage of null keys mechanism change of HashMap in JDK 1.6 or above version?

Tags: java, hashmap

I found that some code is changed for **null keys** in class HashMap in JDK 1.6 or above version compared to the previous JDK version, like 1.5.

In JDK1.5, a static final Object named **NULL_KEY** is defined: **static final Object NULL_KEY = new Object();**

Methods, including `maskNull`, `unmaskNull`, `get` and `put` etc, will use this object.

See

```
static final Object NULL_KEY = new Object();
static <T> T maskNull(T key) {
    return key == null ? (T)NULL_KEY : key;
}
static <T> T unmaskNull(T key) {
    return (key == NULL_KEY ? null : key);
}

public V get(Object key) {
    Object k = maskNull(key);    
    int hash = hash(k);        
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length); 
    Entry<K,V> e = table[i];             
    while (true) {                        
        if (e == null)
            return null;
        if (e.hash == hash && eq(k, e.key))
            return e.value;
        e = e.next;
    }
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    K k = maskNull(key);                             
    int hash = hash(k);                             
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);             
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.hash == hash && eq(k, e.key)) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);              
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;                                       
    addEntry(hash, k, value, i);                      
    return null;
}
```

However, such Object (NULL_KEY) is not used in JDK 1.6 or above version.

Instead, two new methods named **`getForNullKey()`** and **`putForNullKey(value)`** is added, which are applied in **`get`** and **`put`** method as well.

See the source code as follows:

```
 public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    Entry<K,V> entry = getEntry(key);

    return null == entry ? null : entry.getValue();
}

 private V getForNullKey() {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null)
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
 }

public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}

/**
 * Offloaded version of put for null keys
 */
private V putForNullKey(V value) {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    modCount++;
    addEntry(0, null, value, 0);
    return null;
}
```

Change always has its reason for changing, such as `improving the performance` etc. Please help me out with the following 2 question

**Q#1 ==>** *Why this change is made, is there some scenario that the null keys of HashMap implemented in JDK 1.5 encouneters issue ?*

**Q#2 ==>** *What is the advantage of null keys mechanism change of HashMap in JDK 1.6 or above version?*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belong to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation for **private V getForNullKey()**](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) says

> Offloaded version of get() to look up null keys. Null keys map to
>   index 0. This null case is split out into separate methods **for the
>   sake of performance** in the two most commonly used operations (get and
>   put), but incorporated with conditionals in others.